# Sql server query Use of Any

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a SQL server way to select records that have multiple related records that meet a specific condition.
I came up with this, but it's not working :(

```
select m.* from table1 m
 inner join table2 I on m.Id = I.Id
where 
I.Id = ANY (select t.Id from table2 t where t.Id = I.Id and t.Status = 3) 
and 
I.Id = ANY (select t.Id from table2 t where t.Id = I.Id and t.Status <> 3)
```

The result I want is all records from table1 which has related records on table2. At least one related record should have status 3 and at least one related record should not have status 3.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3):

You need `EXISTS` with `NOT EXISTS` :

```
select m.* 
from table1 m
where exists (select 1 from table2 t where t.Id = m.Id and t.Status = 3) and
      not exists (select 1 from table2 t where t.Id = m.Id and t.Status = 3);
```

Comment: Sir, **At least one related record should have status 3 and at least one related record should not have status 3**, So you shouldn't use `NOT Exists`, Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60720135/9071943).

Comment: . . . You should post a comment before un-accept or vote down.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `EXISTS` like below

```
select m.* 
from table1 m
where 
EXISTS (select TOP 1 t.Id from table2 t where t.Id = m.Id and t.Status = 3) 
and 
EXISTS (select TOP 1 t.Id from table2 t where t.Id = m.Id and t.Status <> 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN`. Just replace `= ANY` with `IN` and your code will work as you have expected.

```
select m.* from table1 m
inner join table2 I on m.Id = I.Id
where 
I.Id IN (select t.Id from table2 t where t.Id = I.Id and t.Status = 3) 
and 
I.Id IN (select t.Id from table2 t where t.Id = I.Id and t.Status <> 3)
```